# Three.js material color is distorting the color of my texture

Tags: three.js

When I use `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` with color `0xffffff`, my textures are incredible washed out. The texture in this example is a solid `#ff6600`. The face below is the topic at hand.

[image: not good]

When I set the underlying material color to `0xff6600` (the same as the texture), I get this result, which is exactly what I want!

[image: perfect]

This is a simplified example. What happens when half white, half orange?

[image: half and half]

In this case, I can have correct orange or correct white, but not both because the material color interferes!

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: what types of lights in the scene and how its color?

Comment: How is the model being loaded and how are you comparing the color? It's possible that the gamma correction is incorrect. Try changing `WebGLRenderer.gammaInput` and `gammaOutput`: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.gammaOutput

Comment: @DonutGaz When you apply a color `c` and a texture `t`, it means you multiply their respective channels: `c.r` * `t.r`, `c.g` * `t.g`, `c.b` * `t.b`, thus, when you have the same values for color and texture you simply get squared values. Means `ff6600` = vec3(1, 0.4, 0), then (1, 0.4, 0) * (1, 0.4, 0) = (1, 0.16, 0).

Comment: @prisoner849 is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @GarrettJohnson gammaInput=true fixed this :)